# Am I tripping or do some of my boarders seem darker than others?

Tags: html, css

I made a chess board in html and css and some of my boarders seem to 'jump out' more than others. Can anybody give me a second opinion please?

[image]

Like look at the dark square boarders with the parameter, like the bottom of square c1 compared to b1.

Each of my rows in html looks like this (this is the sixth row with some squares taken out):

```
<tr><td class = "Numbers">6</td><td row = "2" col = "0" id = "17" data-chess-piece="none" class="square light"></td></tr>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
td {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding:0px;
    border:3px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table{
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: You just gotta zoom in, and look at them closely to know that they are the same colors. The problem is the white background against your dark-red background/black lines.

Comment: Optical Illusion! Now was that 3 'i's or 'L's?

Comment: You can use a drawing program with an eye-dropper/color-picker tool or a standalone color-picker tool to find any color on your screen.   Just say no to drugs (except for beer, beer is fine).

Comment: that's a visual illusion, cause that brown color is not as contrasting as white. you might want to change the brown color to something else, or just a lighter brown

Comment: It is not merely a 'visual illusion'. The way monitors render color is also an important factor: the entire pixel is not always used. So while the colors are 'correct' (subject to anti-aliasing), even assuming the same width, the physical manifestation is inherently flawed - even before the brain applies it's own bias. Furthermore, to account for zoom and DPI browsers may not even render *exactly* two physical pixels. If some lines are rendered wider (either in whole pixel on in aliased pixel increments) then this will also affect perception.

Comment: Nice chessboard. Did you use SVG?

Comment: Nope, regular old png's

Answer (score 3):

You're trippin' (:

It's simply the contrast between the brown and white tiles that can play mind games with you.  They are indeed the same color.

Comment: Thats what I thought, I think I'll take @Aziz suggestion and make the brown lighter